# SMACSS how to identify what to put in modules?

Tags: css, sass, smacss

I've just started learning front end web development and a few days ago I got familiar with SMACSS methodology. I've red the concept on the official website and a couple of other articles. But I am still very confused with modules.

What I understood is that I should create a partial for any little element that's inside a layout.

For example let's say, that there is a sidebar that contains just headline and paragraph. As I understood, the sidebar itself will go to layouts. But where should I style headline and paragraph? Are they going to separate modules or I should just simply write them in the layout?

This is just an example, but I have a lot of struggles like this while trying to use SMACSS. Could anybody please explain me this part in a easy and simple way?

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials on this on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest thing that you can do is learn how to do basic things in `react.js`. How to work with react components. They are basically separate modules. Every component should have its own styles.

Look here for example: https://blog.risingstack.com/the-react-way-getting-started-tutorial/#howshouldiimagineit

There is this really cool image that describes what should be component.

[image]